# Using data in Typescript, Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a request in Angular 5:

```
http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')                           
    .subscribe(result => {
        this.std = (result as Students[]);
    }, error => console.error(error));
```

Interface:

```
interface Students {
    Address: string;
    Email: string;
    Phone: string;
    StdName: string;
}
```

I place data in `std` , `public std : Students[]`. How i can turn to certain object? (like `std[1].Email` etc.)

Help please!

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more on what do you want to achieve?

Comment: the current value and the expected result

Comment: Why `(result as Students[])` instead `(result as Students)`?

Comment: I get data form DB . In std i have many records. For example, I want get email of certain interface oject. I understanding `std` like array and do this like std[1].Email, but its wrong. Hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this , this way if you are getting **array** of `Students` in response

```
http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')
.subscribe(result:Students[] => {
    this.std = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
```

But if you are getting **single** `Student` then

```
http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')
.subscribe(result:Students => {
    this.std.push(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I cant declare result like `result :Students` or `result: Students[]`

Comment: @St.S, that's why I have defined both , if you are getting multiple students in result then go for first , if not then go for second

Comment: @St.S , as per the request url , i think second one will give you perfect result

Comment: sorry, i understand it, but i have error when i try `result : Students[]`. i getting multiple students

Comment: Will you please post the result you are getting ?

Comment: i should make request in constructor , isn it?

Comment: @St.S, nope there is nothing wrong in this , you can do this way.

Comment: when i try declare `result` like `result : Student[]` (i changed name of class) i get many errors https://i.imgur.com/tIjsyqt.png

Answer (score 0):

1. A class should be singular, not plural

   ```
   export class Student { ... }
   ```
2. You should use a class, to instantiate objects, and not an interface.
3. you don't need to affect a type to your variable like this. Declare the type when you declare your variable instead.

   ```
   std: Student[];
   ```
4. To access properties of your object, you can do this.

   ```
   this.std.length; // Array properties
   this.std[0].Phone; // Properties of the first student
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answer! i do it, but how i should change my request?

Comment: Why would you change your request ?

Comment: i get error "  Cannot read property '0' of undefined"  when i try acces to `this.std[0].Phone`  . How i should be define `std`?

Comment: The issue isn't how you defined `std` it's how you get your data. Make a console log in your `subscribe`, and tell me what it is logging.

Comment: sorry, log of `result`?

Comment: exactly :) where are you making your current console log ?

Comment: Oh well, of course you're not getting anything ! To call a log in your console, you first have to select your component, then use `ng.probe($0).componentInstance.std`

Comment: get the same log

Comment: have some ideas?